# Can I rely the order of Files in archive/zip.Reader.File?

Tags: go, zip

I am writing an app that would allow random access to files in a zip archive based on the md5sum of the files. To do that, I am planning to map each hashsum to a tuple of `(zip_file, file_index)`.

Can I rely on the order of Files in [`archive/zip.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Reader)? I presume it's same as the order of files in the archive but couldn't find any resources.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure, as a practical matter, you can rely on that, even if it's not a documented behavior. It would be odd to write an implementation that returns files in an order other than that in which they are found in the archive.

Comment: @Flimzy I thought so too, thanks. =)